# Generate scaffold which references a model who refers another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have 2 existing models: `post` and `post_reply`, the latter referring to the former. I want to create another model using scaffolding which references `post_reply`. What should be the name of my column name in the generate command to refer `post_reply` correctly?
Using rails 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "references" and by that I assume you mean `belongs_to`

```
rails generate scaffold new_model post_reply:references
```

The column name generated will be `post_reply_id` and you can just create the column directly.

```
rails generate scaffold new_model post_reply_id:integer
```

If you do the latter, you'll need to add the `belongs_to` line manually to `NewModel`

The integer column can actually be called anything you want but calling it `post_reply_id` is expected and respects the advice of 'convention over configuration'.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how should the table being referred to be named in the command. Earlier I tried PostReply which generated vague results. Also tried post_reply but I forgot to run the migration.